# Cannot feed value of shape: Misunderstanding Tensor Dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I've been walking through some tensorflow tutorials and am cobbling together a pet experiment. However, I am running into some dimension errors and I can seem to figure them out.

My goal: I have an input matrix for the shape 1xN. I have a training set of dimension 10xN. (1 and 10 were chosen arbitrarily). N is intended to represent N samples in a training set: 1 input value mapped to one vector of outputs. You can think of this as 1 input neuron and m output neurons. The training set is a set of these single values mapped to a 1d vector. I wish to train the network by running the set of these mapped inputs and outputs against it and reducing the error.

The simple algorithm that I am trying to accomplish:

1. For each value in the input vector

   2. Load the input neuron with that value
   3. Feed forward
   4. Evaluate against the corresponding vector

Repeat to minimize error.

However, I seem to be getting mixed up with how to format the data to feed to the network. I have a placeholder of 1 input neurons and one of n output neurons. I want to follow the above algorithm but I am not sure if I am doing it right:

```
# Data parameters

num_frames = 10

stimuli_value_low = .00001
stimuli_value_high = 100

pixel_value_low = .00001
pixel_value_high = 256.0

stimuli_dimension = 1
frame_dimension = 10

stimuli = np.random.uniform(stimuli_value_low, stimuli_value_high, (stimuli_dimension, num_frames))
frames = np.random.uniform(pixel_value_low, pixel_value_high, (frame_dimension, num_frames))

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_iterations = 1000
display_iteration = 10

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 100
n_hidden_2 = 100
num_input_neurons = stimuli_dimension
num_output_neurons = frame_dimension

# Create placeholders
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_input_neurons])
output_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_output_neurons])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input_neurons, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, num_output_neurons]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_output_neurons]))
}

# Create model
def neural_net(input_placeholder):
    # Hidden fully connected layer 
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_placeholder, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    # Hidden fully connected layer
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each pixel
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Construct model
logits = neural_net(input_placeholder)

# Define loss operation and optimizer
loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = output_placeholder))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
train_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)

# Evaluate model (with test logits, for dropout to be disabled)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(output_placeholder, 1))
accuracy_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start Training
with tf.Session() as sess:

  # Run the initializer
  sess.run(init)

  for step in range(1, training_iterations + 1): 

    sess.run(train_operation, feed_dict = {X: stimuli, Y: frames})

    if iteration % display_iteration == 0 or iteration == 1:

      loss, accuracy = sess.run([loss_operation, accuracy_operation], feed_dict = {X: stimuli, Y: frames})

      print("Step " + str(iteration) + 
            ", Loss = " + "{:.4f}".format(loss) + 
            ", Training Accuracy= " + \
            "{:.3f}".format(acc))

  print("Optimization finished!")
```

I think it is something to do with how I am structuring my data or feeding it to the run function.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-420-7517598734d6> in <module>()
      6   for step in range(1, training_iterations + 1):
      7 
----> 8     sess.run(train_operation, feed_dict = {X: stimuli, Y: frames})
      9 
     10     if iteration % display_iteration == 0 or iteration == 1:

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1147                              'which has shape %r' %
   1148                              (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name,
-> 1149                               str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1150           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1151             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

How can I ensure I am formatting my input data correctly and forming my network corresponingly?

Comment: Did you provide all of the code?  I don't see where `X` or `Y` are defined from `sess.run(train_operation, feed_dict = {X: stimuli, Y: frames})`

Comment: stimuli and frames are defined under # Data parameters at the top.

Comment: But what about `X` and `Y`?

Comment: This is a good observation. I was following along in a tutorial and assumed that X and Y were just internal variable names that the inputs and outputs are fed to. But after looking some things up it seems that they are supposed to be the variables that the placeholders are assigned to. Should it be `sess.run(train_operation, feed_dict = {input_placeholder: stimuli, output_placeholder: frames})`? I am confused about the role of placeholders vs raw data here.

Comment: That seems like it might be right, the keys in the dictionary should be tensors, while the values should be numpy arrays.

Comment: Yes it fixed a problem. Thanks for pointing that out! Turns out the answer to my question about dimensionality was because I had the dimensions of the stimuli and frames backward. See answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had the dimensions of the arrays I was generating backwards:

```
stimuli = np.random.uniform(stimuli_value_low, stimuli_value_high, (stimuli_dimension, num_frames))
frames = np.random.uniform(pixel_value_low, pixel_value_high, (frame_dimension, num_frames))
```

should be:

```
stimuli = np.random.uniform(stimuli_value_low, stimuli_value_high, (num_frames, stimuli_dimension))
frames = np.random.uniform(pixel_value_low, pixel_value_high, (num_frames, frame_dimension))
```